# How do I convert, display and store this characters in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this set of code which may randomly read a webpage and output the page title to the user, depending on what they input in the url field, it might be an English site, Chinese, Russian or whatever. But the problem is it keeps on displaying garbled text: ¹ù¸»³Ç - Google ËÑË÷

Anyone have idea is greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php

$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

if( !@$DOM->loadHTMLFile( 'http://www.google.com.sg/search?hl=zh-CN&biw=1366&bih=636&q=%E9%83%AD%E5%AF%8C%E5%9F%8E&oq=%E9%83%AD%E5%AF%8C%E5%9F%8Ea&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6545l6545l0l1l1l0l0l0l0l295l295l2-1l1aa' ) ) {
    die('cannot load!');
}
else {
    $XPath = new DOMXPath( $DOM );
    $title = strip_tags( $XPath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue );
    echo $title; exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: What database server are you using? Check the character set being used.

Comment: Its not the database that is the issue. No database involve here. I am reading a webpage dynamically from php.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're right. I clearly didn't read the question very carefully.

Comment: Perhaps try dumping the text to a file and see if it displays correctly there.

Comment: That's completely unrelated and not constructive, but I just love how `!@$DOM` makes it look like your code is swearing.

Comment: On a more constructive note, is it possible that the file `loadHTMLFile` receives is not UTF-8 and isn't converted properly?

Comment: Michael: I was hoping to output this dynamically to the user if its possible?

Comment: zneak: Its the same even if I use file_get_content. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `&oe=utf-8` to the query string and use [`utf8_decode()`](https://www.php.net/utf8_decode) when outputting the data, that should solve your problem:

```
$title = utf8_decode(strip_tags($XPath->query('//title')->item(0)->nodeValue));
```

Comment: Hey francois! Thanks works now, I kept using utf8_encode previously. Anyway thanks all for the great help & suggestion!

Comment: Sorry, but `utf8_decode` converts UTF-8 into ISO 8859-1 and the output returned are absolutely not encodable with ISO 8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

Google does some user agent sniffing to choose an appropriate output encoding. I’m not sure what user agent PHP’s *DOMDocument* uses and what the returned character encoding is, but you can force a particular output encoding by using the `oe=utf-8` URL parameter.

Comment: I tried putting oe=utf-8 and the output is different but still garbled :(

é­å¯å - Google æç´¢

Comment: @pakito: Then you’re probably not [specifying your output encoding properly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#spec-char-encoding) as UTF-8.

Comment: I have basically exhausted my options. I even tried using

    mb_convert_encoding( $title, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($title, "ascii, cp1252, iso-8859-1, utf-8", true) );

Would appreciate if you could advise me on output properly please?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting utf-8 as your content type in PHP...

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You should be returning the content encoding used by the source page (or explicitly converting the page to utf-8)