# How can I decode UTF8 characters using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf8-decode

I recently just solved the issue of outputting foreign characters using utf8_decode function in this thread: [How do I convert, display and store this characters in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495158/how-do-i-convert-display-and-store-this-characters-in-php)

It works by directly echoing the results out but now I have this json_encode function to pass to jquery for the results. Json_encode is escaping my data to something like this:

```
{"title":"\u90ed\u5bcc\u57ce - \u641c\u7d22"}
```

How do I json_decode from jquery?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by asking *How do I json_decode from jquery?* ?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand the answer to the question you link. How can `utf8_encode()` be of any help in a site that uses UTF-8. That function produces `ISO-8859-1` output!

Comment: Hi Alvaro, if you refer to my previous thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495158/how-do-i-convert-display-and-store-this-characters-in-php

You can understand why I need to utf8_decode the string. Only when I utf8_decode the string, I can echo the foreign characters out directly with PHP. But now I realised that decoding it and pass to json will have this issue :(

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396560/how-do-i-convert-special-utf-8-chars-to-their-iso-8859-1-equivalent-using-javasc/26887395#26887395


might help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are writing it directly into JS, in which case do nothing or you are using one of ajax methods in jQuery, in which case just specify the `dataType` to be `"json"`

Comment: Hi you are right Quentin. It works once I set this. Thank you very and thanks all those who replied for help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery offers the `parseJSON` method straight from the `jQuery` object:

```
var data = $.parseJSON('{"title":"\u90ed\u5bcc\u57ce - \u641c\u7d22"}');
```

For fetching data via AJAX, though, `$.getJSON` will run this internally and pass the result of `$.parseJSON` as the request's final result.

Comment: I have this parseJSON in jquery but apparently not working :(

Comment: @pakito: Well, the method is failing because it's coming out as something like `$.parseJSON({title: "the title"})`. `parseJSON` expects a string, not an object. But! Since JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, and this is trusted content, you can just drop the result of `json_encode` into the script: `'var obj = ' . $title . ';'`

Comment: But apart from title, I have other data hence as an array, hence I need to use json_encode to pass to jquery?

Comment: Any one with any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{"title":"\u90ed\u5bcc\u57ce - \u641c\u7d22"}');
```

Comment: I got Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character

The testing code can be save and run directly here: http://pastie.org/2130655